# Sphinxdoc/Readthedocs: redirect a "flat" structure to a hierarchical one

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have a Sphinxdoc page on readthedocs with a large number (>1000) of hierarchically sorted pages, https://iraf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tasks/index.html.
My problem is now that I also need to access them in a "flat" structure, i.e.

https://iraf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tasks/addstar.html

should redirect to

https://iraf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tasks/noao/digiphot/daophot/addstar.html

How could one do this? The exact URL does not matter; important is that there is a need to access the pages just by the name (like `addstar` in the example). There are a few conflicts (i.e. the same name at different places in the hierarchy), but they could be solved in a pragmatic "take the first one" approach.

Comment: Not sure but maybe this helps: https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-reredirects/

Comment: That is actually the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sphinx extension [`sphinx-reredirects`](https://documatt.gitlab.io/sphinx-reredirects/) might do what you want.

You could also configure Read The Docs through [User-defined Redirects](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-defined-redirects.html).